Which versions to install to make RandomFields, RandomFieldsUtils, rpy2 compatible?
I am hoping to install some packages that people no longer update.
I need RandomFields (https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/RandomFields/), RandomFieldsUtils (https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/RandomFieldsUtils/), as well as rpy2.   Which verisons should I pick to install in my conda environment?  Currently, I have r-base 4.1.2, python  3.12.3, r-randomfields 3.3.14, and r-randomfieldsutils 1.2.5.  But, with this setup, I cannot install rpy2, with the following error message,
Could not solve for environment specs
The following packages are incompatible
├─ pin-1 is installable and it requires
│  └─ python 3.12.* , which can be installed;
├─ r-base 4.1.2**  is requested and can be installed;
└─ rpy2 is not installable because there are no viable options
   ├─ rpy2 3.5.11 would require
   │  └─ r-base >=4.2,<4.3.0a0 , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
   ├─ rpy2 [2.8.1|2.8.2|2.8.5|2.8.6] would require
   │  └─ python [2.7* |>=2.7,<2.8.0a0 ], which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
   ├─ rpy2 [2.8.1|2.8.2|...|2.9.4] would require
   │  └─ python [3.5* |>=3.5,<3.6.0a0 ], which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
   ├─ rpy2 [2.8.5|2.8.6|2.9.1|2.9.2|2.9.3] would require
   │  └─ python 3.6* , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
   ├─ rpy2 [2.9.0|2.9.1|...|3.4.5] would require
   │  └─ python >=3.6,<3.7.0a0 , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
   ├─ rpy2 [2.9.1|2.9.4|...|3.5.1] would require
   │  └─ python >=3.7,<3.8.0a0 , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
   ├─ rpy2 [3.1.0|3.3.2|...|3.5.9] would require
   │  └─ python >=3.8,<3.9.0a0 , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
   ├─ rpy2 [3.3.2|3.3.6|...|3.5.9] would require
   │  └─ python >=3.9,<3.10.0a0 , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
   ├─ rpy2 [3.4.5|3.5.1|...|3.5.9] would require
   │  └─ python >=3.10,<3.11.0a0 , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
   ├─ rpy2 [3.5.1|3.5.10|...|3.5.9] would require
   │  └─ python >=3.11,<3.12.0a0 , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
   ├─ rpy2 3.5.11 would require
   │  └─ r-base >=4.3,<4.4.0a0 , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
   ├─ rpy2 2.7.0 would require
   │  └─ r-base 3.2.2* , which does not exist (perhaps a missing channel);
   ├─ rpy2 2.7.0 would require
   │  └─ python 3.3* , which does not exist (perhaps a missing channel);
   └─ rpy2 [2.8.1|2.8.2|2.8.5] would require
      └─ python 3.4* , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported.

How do I find a compatible collection of archived packages?  Thank you!
The randomfields and randomfieldsutils that I installed were out in early 2022, so I tried to install r-base released around that time period, too.

Maybe don't rely on conda? It is not that widespread among R users (that are not also heavy Python users).

What is your channel configuration? I would try to create a new environment, specifying all packages that I need at creation time, including any versions I absolutely rely on.
